# If I have a given matrix A and I perform it a row/column operation on it to get a new matrix B, are A and B similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

I wonder if the matrices are similar, and if this is true, then if I want to solve a minimal polynomial problem on a matrix A, if I can simplify the matrix A until it has the form of a diagonal matrix by blocks B.

Comment: There was a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126389/why-does-gaussian-elimination-not-preserve-similarity-of-a-matrix) on the topic of similarity preservation in Gaussian elimination. Under some circumstances, the row/column operations *can* preserve similarity (anyway in $P^{-1}AP$, $P$ and $P^{-1}$ realize certain row and column operations as well). However, you cannot use it to *diagonalize* any matrix since for sufficiently large matrices, no finite algorithm for computing eigenvalues exists unless the matrix is very special (e.g., diagonal, triangular, etc.).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Do row/column operations necessarily maintain the trace of the matrix? (Two similar matrices have the same trace.)

Answer (score 5):

Elementary row and column operations transforma a matrix $A$ in another matrix $B$ that is said to be **[equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence)**, and we can find two matrices $Q$ and $P$ such that: $B=Q^{-1}AP$. Note that here $A$ and $B$ may well be rectangular matrices and all we can say about these is that tey have the same rank.

**[Similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity)** is only defined for square matrices and require: $B=P^{-1}AP$. This is a more strong request, and implies that $A$ and $B$ have the same characteristic polynomial, so same determinant, same trace, same eigenvalues etc.
For square matrices obviously similarity implies equivalence, but not vice versa .

Comment: Also, to illustrate that for square matrices equivalence is a much coarser (easy to satisfy) relation that similarity, there are only finitely many classes for equivalence (given by the _rank_, which is a non-negative integer bounded by the size) while there are _infinitely many_ classes for similarity (the characteristic polynomial being an invariant for similarity).